# Import django setting in a app for test

Tags: django, python-3.x

I would like to import django setting in API_script.py in API
the settings are in Agora.settings :

Here is my API_script.py in API :

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "Agora.settings")
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
import django
from django.db.models.loading import cache as model_cache
from Profile.models import Profile_User
try :
    django.setup()
except :
     pass

def check_profile_exist(token):
    print(token)
```

Here is the error that i get :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bussiere/WorkspaceSafe/Agora/API/API_script.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from django.middleware.csrf import rotate_token
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/middleware/csrf.py", line 14, in <module>
    from django.utils.cache import patch_vary_headers
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/utils/cache.py", line 26, in <module>
    from django.core.cache import caches
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/cache/__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    if DEFAULT_CACHE_ALIAS not in settings.CACHES:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 48, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 44, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 92, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: No module named 'Agora'
```

And here my tree file :

```
.
    ├── Agora
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── __pycache__
    │   │   ├── __init__.cpython-34.pyc
    │   │   ├── settings.cpython-34.pyc
    │   │   ├── urls.cpython-34.pyc
    │   │   └── wsgi.cpython-34.pyc
    │   ├── settings.py
    │   ├── urls.py
    │   └── wsgi.py
    ├── API
    │   ├── admin.py
    │   ├── API_script.py
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── migrations
    │   │   ├── __init__.py
    │   │   └── __pycache__
    │   │       └── __init__.cpython-34.pyc
    │   ├── models.py
    │   ├── __pycache__
    │   │   ├── admin.cpython-34.pyc
    │   │   ├── API_script.cpython-34.pyc
    │   │   ├── __init__.cpython-34.pyc
    │   │   ├── models.cpython-34.pyc
    │   │   └── views.cpython-34.pyc
    │   ├── tests.py
    │   ├── unit_test.py
    │   └── views.py
    ├── Contact
    │   ├── admin.py
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── models.py
    │   ├── __pycache__
    │   │   ├── admin.cpython-34.pyc
    │   │   ├── __init__.cpython-34.pyc
    │   │   └── models.cpython-34.pyc
    │   ├── tests.py
    │   └── views.py
    ├── Dockerfile
    ├── generateadm.py
    ├── IMG_20150928_105102.jpg
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── manage.py
    ├── Message
    │   ├── admin.py
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── models.py
    │   ├── __pycache__
    │   │   ├── admin.cpython-34.pyc
    │   │   ├── __init__.cpython-34.pyc
    │   │   ├── models.cpython-34.pyc
    │   │   └── views.cpython-34.pyc
    │   ├── tests.py
    │   └── views.py
    ├── Mock
    │   ├── admin.py
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── models.py
    │   ├── __pycache__
    │   │   ├── admin.cpython-34.pyc
    │   │   ├── __init__.cpython-34.pyc
    │   │   ├── models.cpython-34.pyc
    │   │   └── views.cpython-34.pyc
    │   ├── tests.py
    │   └── views.py
    ├── Profile
    │   ├── admin.py
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── models.py
    │   ├── profile_script.py
    │   ├── __pycache__
    │   │   ├── admin.cpython-34.pyc
    │   │   ├── __init__.cpython-34.pyc
    │   │   ├── models.cpython-34.pyc
    │   │   └── profile_script.cpython-34.pyc
    │   ├── tests.py
    │   └── views.py
    ├── Queue
    │   ├── admin.py
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── models.py
    │   ├── __pycache__
    │   │   ├── admin.cpython-34.pyc
    │   │   ├── __init__.cpython-34.pyc
    │   │   └── models.cpython-34.pyc
    │   ├── tests.py
    │   └── views.py
    ├── requierement.txt
    ├── result.txt
    └── runserver.sh
```

regards and thanks

Comment: I agree with the answers, use sys.path.append. Also, you should use lowercases only for modules/packages names in Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you appended the django project path to python's path?

e.g.

```
import os, sys
BASE_PATH="/location/folder/where/manage.py/lives"
sys.path.append(BASE_PATH)
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'Agora.settings'
```

Comment: Please see also my answer for a more Django-friendly approach ;)

Comment: Agreed given the information @baxeico's answer is a better option and should be accepted.

Answer (score 2):

While the sys.path issues pointed out by other answers is probably your current problem, it seems that for your use case (a script that does "something" on an app) a [Django custom command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-management-commands/) is more well suited.

It is very easy to setup a custom command:

Create the path `management/commands` in your API folder. Do not forget to add empty `__init__.py` files in both `management` and `commands` folders.

Then create a Python module named for example `apiscript.py` inside the `management/commands` folder, with this content:

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
from Profile.models import Profile_User

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Describe the purpose of your script'

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        # do something with Profile_User model
        p = Profile_User.objects.get(pk=1)
```

You have all the Django machinery already set up (no need to call django.setup()) and you can call your script with:

```
./manage.py apiscript
```

Answer (score 1):

It is more than likely the case that the project `Agora` is not on the python path.

There are two ways you can add it to the path depending on your situation.

**Firstly:** Depending on your OS you can symlink the `Agora` projects into the python path directory. This is easily done on linux and OSX and not so easy on windows. It will be something like:

```
ln -s /path/to/Agora /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Agora
```

**Secondly:** Add the following code before your application code:

```
import sys
import os
agora_path = os.path.join('/path/to/library')
sys.path.append(agora_path)

# now add your code
# ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used your ideas and made it agnostic :

```
import os
import sys
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
sys.path.append(BASE_DIR)
print(BASE_DIR)
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "Agora.settings")
```

thanks